# JQuery slimScroll issue with getting div to scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar, slimscroll

I am a complete novice with JQuery!

So here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hYEzV/977/

Fullscreen:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/hYEzV/977/show/

I've add the plug-in in the external resources panel.

My div that I want to attach the scroll to has the id of "sc" and it is wrapped inside a div with the id of **"AboutMe"**

My JQuery code is located right at the bottom of the JS panel and is this:

```
$('#sc').slimScroll({
    position: 'right',
    height: '100%',
    color: '#ffffff',
    railVisible: true,
    alwaysVisible: true
});
```

For some reason it isn't scrolling the div I can see the scroll bar to the right that is coming up but it can't be dragged nor is it changing color to white....

I can't see a problem with it so any help I would love
and thank you in advance for solving if you can!

Answer (score 0):

Solved forgot to add JQuery UI in resources.